# r subsetting matrix by rows using logical vector

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

A sparse matrix keeps rows of values in a matrix. The category for each row is in a separate vector of factors

e.g., suppose the data is measurement dimensions for boxes

*valueMatrix:*

```
5,8,8
1,2,1
6,8,9
3,4,4
```

Each box is classified as 1, small, 2 medium, 3, large
so there is a vector of factors:

*factorVector*

```
3,1,3,2
```

I want to subset the matrix so I only get the big boxes like this:

```
5,8,8
6,8,9
```

So I create a logical vector from the vector of factors

```
vLogical <-as.Numeric(valueMatrix)==3
```

which creates

```
TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
```

But my understanding is that I can only select columns using a logical vector. Am I correct?
Do I then need to transpose the matrix before subsetting and then transpose back again (so I can run a PCA on the subset)?
NOTE by dataset is a few hundred thousand rows and 500+ variables so it is significant processing

Comment: "I can only select columns using a logical vector" - incorrect. you can subset rows too. `matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)[c(T,F,T,F,F),]` and `matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)[, c(T,F,T,F,F)]`

Comment: Thank you! As you can see, I'm still learning :)